# django-autocomplete-light's suggestions displayed beyond the drop-down list

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates, django-autocomplete-light

For some reason, suggestions from `django-autocomplete-light 3.5.0` are displayed beyond the drop-down list, to the right (there's narrow blue rectangle visible that indicates suggestions):
[image]
I'm able to reverse the widget's url and obtain correct suggestions. Everything's working fine but rendering - when I click on this narrow rectangle, correct value appears in the edit box. I collected all the static files. I'm working on Linux 20.04 LTS, Chrome 83.0.4103.106, python 3.7.7, django 3.0.3, bootstrap 4.5.0 and font-awesome 4.7.0. Here is the code (except settings) that I wrote
`forms.py`

```
class OpinionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # user field is defined as hidden and disabled such that it couldn't be changed
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput,
        queryset=get_user_model().objects.all(),
        disabled=True
    )

    # defining all the fields with autocomplete feature
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Country.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url="country_autocomplete")
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Opinion
        fields = ("content",)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["country"].label = "Kraj"
        self.fields["content"].label = "Treść"
```

`models.py`

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Opinion(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("add_opinion", views.CreateOpinionView.as_view(), name="add_opinion"),
    path("country-autocomplete/", CountryAutocomplete.as_view(create_field="name"),
]
```

`views.py`

```
class CountryAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Country.objects.none()
        qs = Country.objects.all()
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
        return qs

class CreateOpinionView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = OpinionForm
    template_name = "opinions/create.html"

    def get_initial(self):
        """
        When our view is instantiating the form, it will pass the result of get_initial() as the 'initial'
    argument and the POST data as the 'data' argument

    :return:
    """
    return {
        "user": self.request.user.id
    }

def form_valid(self, form):
    """
    If a form is valid, CreateView will call form_valid.
    If the form isn't valid, CreateView will re-render the template.

    :param form:
    :return:
    """
    action = self.request.POST.get("action")
    # when we want to save, we will call the original form_valid method
    # the original method saves the new opinion
    if action == "SAVE":
        # save and redirect as usual
        return super().form_valid(form)
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

`create.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}Dodaj opinię{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Dodaj opinię</h1>
        <form method="post">
            {{ form | crispy }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="action" value="SAVE">Zapisz</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js" %}"></script>
    {{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine for me, so the error must be somewhere else, probably somewhere in your CSS.

[image]

Your code had two errors that prevented it from running though:

1. on_delete is a required argument for ForeignKey since Django 2.0. Are you sure about the versions you are running?

```
- user = models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
+ user = models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

2. I assume this one was a copy-paste error when creating the question

```
- path("country-autocomplete/", CountryAutocomplete.as_view(create_field="name"),
+ path("country-autocomplete/", CountryAutocomplete.as_view(create_field="name"), name='country_autocomplete'),
```

---

Here are additional details of my setup, perhaps you can find what is different from yours:

Versions:

```
Django==3.0.3
django-autocomplete-light==3.5.0
django-crispy-forms==1.9.1
```

`base.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block footer %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

`settings.py`:

```
# ...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'crispy_forms',
    'yourappname'
]
# ...
# (everything else left at defaults)
```

Comment: You were right, the problem was in the `base.css`, I don't know yet what is the exact cause though